# ExtJS 4.0, Django and ExtDirect

Tags: javascript, python, django, extjs, ext-direct

Do you know if I can use this [Django Ext.Direct router](https://github.com/iancmcc/extdirect) with ExtJS 4.0? Do you have any examples where I can find how to do it? I'm new to JavaScript programming.

Will it be easy to integrate server side form validation with ExtJS? What about file upload?

Can I use ExtJS library drawing (or charts) to draw a hall where clients can click on empty seats and purchase a tickets? Do you know any other ajax library that can help me do this easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you know if I can use this Django
>   Ext.Direct router with ExtJS 4.0?

We recently switched from Ext3 to Ext4 (with Django as backend).

Our experience involved a lot of trouble with changes in the ExtJS 4 API (especially in the area of datagrid stores). All reasonable and good changes but huge. Given the activity of the GitHub project above (2/2010) I would judge it's **nearly 100%** sure that **it will not work** with the current version of ExtJS.

On the other hand ExtJS4 has very good support for backend/frontend conversions (we got rid of a lot of conversions). So I assume there is not that much need for the Django router any more.

> Can I use ExtJS library drawing (or
>   charts) to draw a hall where clients
>   can click on empty seats and purchase
>   a tickets?

This is a **very special use case** and far away form the charting approach in ExtJS (or any other charting lib I know of). ExtJS charts are working with data stores to display basically numerical data. I'm pretty sure you need to write this **from scratch**.

> I'm new to JavaScript programming.

ExtJS is a very sophisticated framework. Prepare for serious stuff. These guys understand JavaScript very well and put it in action as if it is a "real" object oriented language (did I just wrote this - prepare for flamewars. ;-) ).
Seriously, you need to invest some time to understand their philosophy (but it's worth the effort).

Comment: Most of the time we use the Ext.Ajax.request class. We encode our data to JSON (and send it with the parameters) and decode it on the other side (and vice versa with the response). Example: http://snipplr.com/view/9692/extjs--simple-ajax-request-with-callback-and-json-to-object-deserialization/

Comment: I see :) But what about Django Cross Site Request Forgery protection? How you make so Django know that the request is OK?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that your question targets security issues. I'm not able to answer this, because we mainly build B2B applications with a known userbase and (at least I hope) that there is not that much of a need for request validation.